# bounded in Probability gives rate for expectation?

Tags: probability-theory

I have that $n|X_n|$ is bounded in Probability so per definition

\begin{align}
\lim _{n \rightarrow \infty} P\left(n|X_n|>t\right)<\delta
\end{align}
for any $\delta>0$ and all sufficiently large $t$

What i need to show is that
\begin{align}
E(|X_n|)\lesssim \frac{1}{n}
\end{align}
but im not sure anymore if its possible?
what i tried is
\begin{align}
E(|X_n|) < E(|X_n| \chi_{\{|X_n|>\frac{t}{n}\}}) + \frac{t}{n}
\end{align}
And by Cauchy Schwarz we get
\begin{align}
< \sqrt{E(|X_n|^2)}\sqrt{ P\left(n|X_n|>t\right)} + \frac{t}{n}
\end{align}
But now im not sure how t and delta actually relate... so i can not bound the first summand

If it is not true is it at least possible to proof it if $nX_N$ converges in probability to some fixed t?

Comment: What if, say, $X_n=Y/n$, where $Y$ is not integrable, say with  the Cauchy distribution?  Then $nX_n$ is bounded in probability and all $E[|X_n|]=+\infty$.

Comment: You probably meant 'for sufficiently large $n$'?

Comment: so its wrong in generell? is it correct if $nX_n$ converges in Probability to some fixed t ?